# Why is this Mysql query only storing a few fields and throwing error message?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am new to PHP and trying to write a quiz application. I have the following code in my addquestion.php file. But when I use this to add a question, only some columns are added in the table. The ones that throw an error have data-type 'text' or 'varchar'.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Add new question</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/addques.css">
</head>
<body class="text-center">
 <h1>Add question</h1>
 <?php
  session_start();
  //only display the following content to admin
  if($_SESSION['usertype'] == 'admin') {

 ?>
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
   <div>
    <label for="topic">Topic</label>
    <select name="topic" id="topic">
     <option value="1">Logical Reasoning</option>
     <!-- removing other options to shorten the code -->
     <option value="37">MS Windows and Office</option>
    
    </select>
   </div>

   <div>
    <label for="Statement">Question Statement</label>
    <input id="" type="text" name="statement">
   </div>
   <div>
    <label for="Option1">Option 1</label>
    <input id="Option1" type="text" name="option1">
   </div>
   <div>
    <label for="Option2">Option 2</label>
    <input id="Option2" type="text" name="option2">
   </div>
   <div>
    <label for="Option3">Option 3</label>
    <input id="Option3" type="text" name="option3">
   </div>
   <div>
    <label for="Option4">Option 4</label>
    <input id="Option4" type="text" name="option4">
   </div>
   <div>
    <label for="correctans">Correct Answer</label>
    <select name="correctans" id="correctans">
     <option value="a">A</option>
     <option value="b">B</option>
     <option value="c">C</option>
     <option value="d">D</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <div>
    <label for="imagepath">Image URL</label>
    <input id="imagepath" type="text" name="imagepath">
   </div>
   <div>
    <label for="solution">Solution</label>
    <input id="solution" type="textarea" name="solution">
   </div>

   <div>
    
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">
   </div>
  </form>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
 <?php
  // connect to the database
  require_once("connectVars.php");

  $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die("Error connecting to database @ addquestion.php");

  
  //set the variables.
  $statement = $_POST['statement'];
  $option1 = $_POST['option1'];
  $option2 = $_POST['option2'];
  $option3 = $_POST['option3'];
  $option4 = $_POST['option4'];
  $correctans = $_POST['correctans'];
  $imageUrl = $_POST['imagepath'];
  $solution = $_POST['solution'];
  $topicId = $_POST['topic'];

 // add the question
  $query_question = "INSERT into questionbank (statement, option1, option2, option3, option4, correctans, topicId,imagepath)
         VALUES ('$statement', '$option1', '$option2', '$option3', '$option4', '$correctans', '$topicId', '$imageUrl')";

  $addQues = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_question) or die("Error adding question");

  // add the solution
  $query_solution = "INSERT into solutions (solution) VALUES('$solution')";
  $addSol = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_solution) or die("Error adding solution");

  mysqli_close($dbc);
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and show the real error(s). `or die("Error adding XXX");` doesn't help you. Along with http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Looks like these are quotes.

Comment: Btw, you sure have a lot of "Lord knows if they were solved or not" questions. Good luck debugging, it's part of the "fun".

Comment: That comment seems to imply that I just head over to stack overflow and ask a question the first time I see trouble, without trying to solve it myself. If that is the impression I give, well I am sorry.

Comment: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) ... that's how we roll here.

Comment: It implies that some of us look at question history. Some people have 40 Unaccepted answers (like, they have never accepted any, anywhere) and have no idea how the system works

Comment: Yeah exactly that. Stack isn't a debugging service. We help those who help themselves, rather than dumping code on us, getting their answers and running off. Stack was built on giving reputation points to those who give of their free time to help and to continue to be encouraged (oh, and you get points too). We see too many of these types of people, *sigh*.

Comment: Thanks Drew for the explanation. I was under the impression, that I only have to upvote the answer by clicking the 'up' arrow mark. I do debug myself, as far as running away with answers goes, it was purely due to lack of knowledge of the platform here.

Comment: Whats the error message? You are open to XSS and SQL injections with this code.

Comment: Update: I have figured out the problem. The query was working fine but the data I was feeding in contained quotes, which were causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here does not lie with the query itself, but the data which is fed into the form. If it contains single-quotes, the query fails.

Just be careful with the data entered into the form.